# Buildroot generate rootfs with gcc

Tags: gcc, qemu, root-filesystem, buildroot

I wanted to build rootfs using buildroot with preinstalled gcc, but I can't find which config is responsible for building gcc package. What I want is just a rootfs for qemu x86_64. Is there a way in buildroot to include gcc in as a target package?
What i have understood the simple way to achieve this is to copy GCC used by buildroot into rootfs image manually. But I don't fully understand why there is no such option? At least for x86 targets ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems that's buildroot's decision to not to include a compiler in target file system. They aim to reduce image size and see compilation on target as useless.
find more details in their [documentation](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#faq-no-compiler-on-target)